# Visual Studio 2022 cannot find texts that's obviously there

Tags: visual-studio

[image]

Here is the screen shot.

I try to find BRL in Entire solution

It's clearly there. Visual studio even highlight it.

But then I got the message The following specified text was not found

I got to reset my computer and reinstall visual studio 2022

Before it worked fine now it's like this.

**Note**: I uncheck always show this message. Now that box don't show up anymore. How do I undo that.

I can find BRL in "current document" but not if I select current project or current solution.

The file is clearly part of the solution as shown

[image]

However, solution explorer does show too many files. I wonder if there's a way for solution explorer to show only the project files. It used to be that way before I upgrade to .net core.

Visual studio does display too many files though

[image]

It seems that this is a bug.

Other people have similar problems

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ybMUX09UPxc

However his fail only on one pane. I failed in all

Comment: Are you sure that file is included in a project that's active in the solution?  Maybe the file is from another solution, a historical representation from source control, etc.  I always recommend using Ctrl + Shift + F, lieu of that search interface you're showing; the former is much more powerful and reliable.  You can even set it to search beneath a directory instead of in a solution or narrower thing.

Comment: How do I know? everything compile

Comment: Also the search dialog has some settings, where you can define where to search (filetypes, directories ...) Are you sure you didn't exclude the file from the search?

Comment: It used to work just fine. Then I reset computers.

Comment: Well I don't know what else to suggest other than to re-iterate that that search is unreliable (I don't ever use it anymore) and Ctrl + Shift + F (which is a different search interface) is 1000 times more reliable.

Comment: I wonder what files visual studio think is part of the solution or project? How do I know? Visual studio display many files.

Comment: Using ctrl shift F has the exact same problem

Answer (score 1):

This is how I fix it.

I run visual basic installer.

Then I "repair"

[image]

It works.